Issue with Laravel project hosted on AWS -/public url and route errors
I’ve hosted my Laravel project on AWS. The project runs successfully, but the URL includes /public after the directory name. For example: http:////public.
The project is built entirely with Laravel, using Filament for the backend admin panel and Livewire for the frontend pages. I also needed to run the npm run build command due to Livewire requirements.
However, after navigating to /public, all other routes are returning a "Route Not Found" error. Additionally, I want to remove /public from the URL entirely so the project runs directly from the base directory without explicitly mentioning /public.
Could anyone guide me on how to fix this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
Updated the .env file to ensure the APP_URL is correct.
Tried modifying the DocumentRoot in the Apache or NGINX configuration to point to the /public directory.
Checked file permissions for the project to ensure they are properly set.
Attempted to move files from the /public directory to the root directory (not a preferred solution).
Created a .htaccess file in the root directory to redirect to /public.
What I’m Expecting:
The project should run directly from the base URL without /public in the URL.
All routes, including the backend (Filament) and frontend (Livewire), should work without throwing "Route Not Found" errors.
A clean and professional URL structure for the hosted Laravel application.
If anyone has faced a similar issue or has a solution, please share. Thank you!
